# Which type of reference is created by React.createRef()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using to do some animation but I am confused about the use of ref.

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.textRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={this.textRef} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above syntax who is assigning their own reference. textRef is assigned own reference to input box or input box is assigned own reference to textRef? please let me know if you have any confusion regarding my question.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It's a reference to the underlying html DOMNode. [Official Docs: Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

From [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs):

> Refs are created using React.createRef() and attached to React elements via the ref attribute. Refs are commonly assigned to an instance property when a component is constructed so they can be referenced throughout the component.

In your case, you are creating a new Ref for `textRef` and attaching it to the `<input>` component when constructed during the React render call, and when a ref is passed to an element in render, like shown on your input example, a reference to the node becomes accessible at the current attribute of the ref (`textRef.current`).

[To learn and read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

> [Is] `textRef` is assigned own reference to input box or input box is
> assigned own reference to `textRef`?

[Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

> Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in
> the render method.

In this case a reference to the input element's DOMNode is assigned to the React ref `textRef`. This allows you to later get the current ref value to query the DOM node or otherwise access it.

```
this.textRef.current
```

This is the preferable way to access the DOM and DOMNodes over `document.querySelector`.

**Note:** In general it is probably easier/safer/more accurate to think of React refs as reference to a mutable location in memory that persists through render cycles. They are commonly used to access DOM nodes, but can hold any mutable value.